# Is a restart necessary when enabling access to MySQL from outside?

Tags: mysql

If i want to enable remote access to my MySQL server, I know one way to do it through changing the bind-address on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and restart mysql service. Is it possible to do it without restart the MySQL service ? I know we can change some MySQL system variables through command line interface without restart.

Comment: Yes, you need a restart whenever you modify any of the networking options. The listening socket is only initialized at service startup.

Comment: yes you need to restart the service once you have changed in the my.cnf file. Just doing flush privileges will flush other changes like user, host etc changes but commenting out bind address on my.cnf needs service restart.

Comment: SO is for questions about programming, not system or database administration.